# Any ideas on the behaviour of the following integral?

Tags: asymptotics

I am stuck trying to work out  behaviour for large $b$ of the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0dx\,\sin(ae^{-bx})\frac{1-x^b}{1-x},
$$
where $b>0$ and $a>0$ and I choose $x^b=e^{b\log x}$ where the log is the principal value log.

Any suggestions? I naively tried to expand the sine but, of course, the exponentials are wildly divergent.

Comment: Is $b$ an integer? Else, what is $x^b$ when $x$ is negative?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan edited

Comment: Still, what is $x^b$ if $x=-3$ and $b=7/2$?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan $x^b=e^{b\log x}$ where the logarithm is the principal logarithm

Answer (score 2):

since the integral for large $b$ is dominated by $x$ near zero, where it oscillates least rapidly, we can omit the fraction and approximate the integral by the sine integral,

$$I(a,b)=\int_{-\infty}^0 dx \sin(a e^{-bx})=\frac{\pi}{2b}-\frac{1}{b}{\rm Si}(a)$$

here is a numerical comparison of $\int_{-\infty}^0dx\,\sin(ae^{-bx})\frac{1-x^b}{1-x}$ (blue) and $I(a,b)$ (orange) for $a=5$ and varying integer $b$, on a log-linear scale, supporting the asymptotic large-$b$ behaviour.

[image]